# Counter number of items within each time period in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a list of users with a registration timestamp assigned to each one of when they registered.

How can I count how many users registered in each month for my entire user list, which spans 23 months.

So the output should just be 2 columns, one with the month+year and the other how many users signed up in that month.

Can someone suggest a query to do that?

Example Data

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `regdate`) VALUES
(861490, 1314021552),
(944392, 1317760487),
(674263, 1311119415),
(287512, 1305242049),
(125134, 1299310950),
(714619, 1311658393),
(777858, 1312508020),
(812091, 1312918459),
(979515, 1319524143),
(1009713, 1321038952),
(395950, 1307314421),
(552213, 1309435427),
(549979, 1309395329),
(919872, 1316468483),
(385920, 1307196494),
(825096, 1313085971),
(967657, 1318961937),
(136631, 1299825660),
(838405, 1313315222),
(984647, 1319803409),
(239280, 1303860435),
(917747, 1316368790),
(621945, 1310480971),
(1078781, 1324529892),
(897934, 1315556339),
(311070, 1305899412),
(830274, 1313157183),
(518156, 1308952471),
(524182, 1309037939),
(524142, 1309037521);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(regdate), '%Y-%m') AS month, 
       COUNT(*) AS registrations 
FROM users 
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: this produces a bunch of garbage data with most registrations being in NULL month and the rest in 2013.

Comment: then please post exact table structure and example data.

Comment: Your regdate is int, not timestamp (mysql meaning), I'll edit my answer to reflect that.